# Can a global sensitivity analysis be performed on Bayesian inference?

Tags: bayesian, inference, sensitivity-analysis

My question is, is it possible to perform a Global Sensitivity Analysis on a Bayesian inference model (not just on the prior, the entire model)?

A bit of context:
I am fairly new to Bayesian statistics.
Being a research student in astrobiology, I have read a few papers using Bayesian approaches to try constraining the probability of detecting life on an exoplanet (e.g. [Catling et al. (2018)](https://www.liebertpub.com/doi/10.1089/ast.2017.1737)).

Several papers use the equation below as a starting point:

$$P(\text{life}|D,C) = \frac{P(D|\text{life},C) * P(\text{life}|C)}{P(D|C,\text{life}) * P(\text{life}|C) + P(D|C,\text{no life}) * P(\text{no life} |C)}$$

Where $\text{life}$ and $\text{no life}$ are the hypotheses of the exoplanet to host life and not host life, respectively. $D$ is the data collected from the exoplanet, and $C$ is the exoplanetary context (stellar properties, etc...). Here, the "prior" terms are $P(\text{life}|C)$ and $P(\text{no life}|C)$. The "likelihood" term is $P(D|\text{life}, C)$ and the "false positive" term is $P(D|C, \text{no life})$.

I then simply added $n$ and $i$ indices to the above equation to express the Bayesian inference (i.e. "every time new data are collected, we recalculate the posterior, which then becomes the prior for the next inference"):

$$P(\text{life}|D,C)_n = \frac{P(D|\text{life},C)_i * P(\text{life}|C)_{n-1}}{P(D|C,\text{life})_i * P(\text{life}|C)_{n-1} + P(D|C,\text{no life})_i * P(\text{no life} |C)_{n-1}}$$

The few articles I saw about Global Sensitivity Analysis (GSA) on Bayesian frameworks were doing the GSA on the prior probability distribution only and not the entire model.

But I could see how a GSA could give very useful information about the relative importance of each variable and parameters (prior, likelihood of detecting the data, false positive, number of inferences), especially in a mission design and instrumentation context.

So again my question is: is it possible/valid to perform a Global Sensitivity Analysis on the inference expressed above (i.e. the entire model, not just on the prior(s))?

Thanks a lot for any help, I hope it's clear enough!